# Equivariant maps between real linear representations of finitely generated groups

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, modules, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group, ad let $(V,\rho)$ and $(W,\phi)$ be two finite dimensional linear representations of $G$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Given a linear map $f:V\to W$ it's immediate to check whether $f$ is equivariant or not, but I find it hard to find an equivariant map if I'm not given one.

Is there any results that classify or characterize all the equivariant linear maps between the two?

Comment: A zero map is always equivariant.

Comment: Is your context such that thinking about Schur's lemma and such is relevant? Characteristic $0$ over an algebraically closed field? Finite-dimensional? In any case, in many contexts, the only map(s) between irreducibles are either scalar, if they're isomorphic, or $0$ if they're not. That kind of thing? So certainly hard to "guess" an isomorphism if there are few or none...?

Comment: Are you talking about representations of finite groups, arbitrary groups, finite-dimensional algebras, etc? Is the base field algebraically closed, and is the representation theory semi simple? All of these things will affect the answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you @Joppy for the suggestion, I added some detail

Answer (score 1):

Just take an arbitrary linear map and average it over $G$.

Comment: It may happen to result in the zero map, though.